# how to use pm2 to deploy to Windows stack

Tags: node.js, ssh, windows-7-x64, pm2

## Environment

- Development machine: Windows 7
- Deploy target: Windows 2012 r2
- NodeJS version `v7.10.1`
- Git `git-bash` `2.9.2.windows.1`

I am trying to deploy a **NodeJS** project using **PM2**

[PM2 deploy](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/)

### My PM2 ecosystem file

```
 deploy : {
        production : {
          user : 'myUser',
          host : '10.1.1.16',
          ref  : 'origin/master',
          repo : 'pshakr@bitbucket.org/pjma/adapter.git',
          path : 'C:\\jhu',
          'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production'
        }
      }
```

I have opened `GIT-Bash` on my development machine and getting the following error while running config file

### Error

```
$ pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production setup
--> Deploying to staging environment
--> on host 10.1.1.16
  ○ hook pre-setup
ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.16 port 22: Connection refused

  setup paths failed

Deploy failed
```

### Will PM2 allow me to deploy to a Windows server? any pointers on how to resolve that?

Comment: From your `git-bash` try to `ssh` to your server

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may need to install SSH server on the **Windows 2012r2** server

[what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

[sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/)

Not sure if that will resolve the PM2 deploy, but should explain the connection refused on port 22